# No carga el ítem seleccionado en un Spinner, usando Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

Cuando selecciono un elemento del `Spinner` no se *setea* ni me muestra el mensaje. Ya intenté haciendo el `spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ....)` dentro del `onCreateView` y me sale error.

¿Por qué el *listener* no captura el evento?

Este es el `OncreateView`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(
    LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState
)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_fragment_mapa_robo, container, false
    );

    //Inflate the layout for this fragment

    spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<>(
        this.getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,lista
    );
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line
    );
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    return view;
}
```

Este son los `listener`.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String texto = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa `adapterView` (padre del elemento) e `i` que es la posición:

```
String texto = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

sería:

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
      //String texto = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();              
        String texto = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),texto, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```